# Wordpress/Redirection plugin - how to redirect migrated blogger=>Wordpress.com `?m=1` links?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wordpress.com, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I've migrated (Google) Blogger blog into Wordpress.com.
The blog is rather large (300+ posts) and I still get 404s multiple times a day due to URLs ending with `?m=1` query param.

e.g.
`https://softwarearchiblog.com/2019/01/technical-debt.html?m=1`

will yield HTTP 404, while

`https://softwarearchiblog.com/2019/01/technical-debt.html`

works fine

I use the [Redirection](https://redirection.me/support/dynamic-urls/) Plugin, which does a fairly good job for various other issues - but I can't define a proper expression in its language.

The issue is around not being able to define the target URL as a regex:
[image]

- Is there any way around it?
- Is there any other plugin that will "do this work" and can live side-by-side with Redirections?
- Since I work with hosted Wordpress.com - I understand I cannot modify the `.htaccess` file for a more generic redirect. Any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

With the Redirection Plugin you can ignore the query parameters:

https://redirection.me/support/matching-a-url/

But I think you'll need an entry for each of your posts.

Comment: this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's possible to do using javascript. You might put this code in the `header.php` or `404.php` file (it depends on your theme) or use this plugin to insert the code [Insert Headers and Footers](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var uri = window.location.toString();
        if (uri.indexOf("&m=1", "&m=1") > 0) {
            var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("&m=1"));              
            window.location.replace(clean_uri);
        }
        var uri = window.location.toString();
        if (uri.indexOf("?m=1", "?m=1") > 0) {
            var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?m=1"));
            window.location.replace(clean_uri);
        }; 
</script>
```